# G1 Unable to get past android boot logo

Tags: htc-dream, boot

I have a T-Mobile G1 (HTC Dream), this morning it vibrated once and then restarted, it then went to the android boot logo went through that and stopped at a black screen.

I've tried pulling the battery and restarting but it has the same problem.

The phone is rooted but it has NO custom boot screen, boot loader, rom. It has stock everything apart from the ability to use root.

Running Android 1.6

Anyone any suggestions, I intend to take it back to T-Mobile tomorrow night when they have late opening hours, but I'd like to get it working before then.

Comment: On mine you can press Call, Menu, and End at the same time to make it reboot, and then hold down Home as it starts, to get to the recovery mode.  I don't know if either of those are present without a custom ROM, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried doing a factory reset (**you'll lose all data)**?

Steps to do a factory reset are found [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/factory-reset-tmobile-g1).

> ```
> 1. Power off the G1
> 2. Hold Home Key + End key for 20 
> seconds or until you see a "triangle with an exclamation point
> and a picture of the G1"
> 3. Open the QWERTY keyboard and hit Alt+W
> 4. Restored!
> ```

Comment: Thanks!! worked like a charm. It appears to be ok now just need to reset everything up again.

Comment: @digital great! :)

Comment: I'm having this same problem, but I'm running CM6.  When I boot I don't even get the T-Mobile screen, I just get a blank one.  I've tried home+end, call+menu+end, etc. with no luck.  Right now I can't boot into anything.  Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: I found this blog post, but his solution is based on actually seeing the T-Mobile screen.  I don't even get that: http://the-dro.com/technology/g1-stuck-on-t-mobile-bootup-screen/